# Product Image Container Size not fitting the image aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css issue where the product image containe for images, both portrait and landscape, with different heights does not adapt to fit the height of the actual image. The container height is based on the tallest image. See attached.

I have used the the following css on the container, but cant get adjust theigh height (shown in light blue)

Thanks

```
#image-23714742567097-0 {
    width: 925px !important;
    max-height: 550px;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: my you can try with `object-fit: cover`

Comment: Thanks - That seems to just make the content of the image cover the available space within the container, not change the container height.